# how to get html code from xml using xslt transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a problem, when i try to get html from an xml with xslt transformation, the xml part that contains the html is:

```
`<DataContent><media media-type="image" style="leftSide"><media-reference data-location="#photo0" mime-type=""/></media><p>p1</p><p>p2</p><p>p3</p></DataContent>
</ContentItem>`
```

but in the html page the retult is:

p1p2p3 //only text,

my xslt code is:

```
<xslt:valueof select="ContentItem/DataContent"/>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What does your XSLT look like?

Comment: -1, how do you expect help about your code when you don't post the code?

Comment: sorry, i don´t have much experience in this

Comment: I think you probably want `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`, but I suspect you have other problems as well.  What are those `media` and `media-reference` elements doing there?  Do you mean to treat them as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I know what you're looking for. In the spirit of helping out, below is a solution and some explanation. I **highly** recommend that you pick up a good book on XSLT and learn the basics from the ground up.

---

When this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ContentItem">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DataContent/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...is applied to the original XML (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<ContentItem>
  <DataContent>
    <media media-type="image" style="leftSide">
      <media-reference data-location="#photo0" mime-type=""/>
    </media>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3</p>
  </DataContent>
</ContentItem>
```

...the wanted result is (*I think*) produced:

```
<media media-type="image" style="leftSide">
  <media-reference data-location="#photo0" mime-type=""/>
</media>
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>
```

Your solution is outputting text because `<xsl:value-of>`, by definition, returns the string value of the nodes/attributes selected.